# Adding alt text to images within a wordpress slider

Tags: php, wordpress, image, alt

I am looking to add Alt text to slider images. I was able to add the line:

```
alt ="<?= $alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>"
```

This line pulled in the alt text for the photos but it is the same alt text for all the photos within the slider. It doesn't seem to loop each alt text to each photo. Below is the code that pulls the images.

```
<?php $_gallery = get_field('project_gallery_photos'); ?>

        <?php if( $_gallery ) { ?>
            <div class="_featured-images">
                <div class="_slider">
                    <?php foreach( $_gallery as $_img ): ?>
                        <div class="_slide">
                            <img src="<?= $_img['photo']['sizes']['project-images']?>" alt ="<?= $alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>"/>

                            <?php if( $_img['photo_title'] || $_img['photo_caption'] ) { ?>
                                <div class="_caption">
                                    <?= $_img['photo_title']? '<b>'.$_img['photo_title'].'</b><br>': '' ?>
                                    <?= $_img['photo_caption'] ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're pulling in as the meta description for the "featured image" of the current global `$post`, which the gallery photos appear to be Advanced Custom Field for.

What you should be pulling in instead would be one of those settings from the [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. If you're using the standard ACF Pro `Gallery` field, the `alt` attribute is included at the first level of the array.

```
alt="<?= esc_attr( $_img['alt'] ); ?>"
```

Otherwise, you should be able to use [`print_r( $_img );`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to find the attribute you need, for instance if your `$_img` contains a `'photo'` key, you may need to use:

```
alt="<?= esc_attr( $_img['photo']['alt'] ); ?>"
```

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `foreach()` | [The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) |
| `print_r()` | [Prints human-readable information about a variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) |
| `esc_attr()` | [Escaping for HTML attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) |
| ACF Gallery | [The Gallery field provides an interactive interface for managing a collection of attachments.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) |

Comment: So the [photo_title] and [photo_caption] are custom fields that are the photo title and photo caption that show up on the slider. I am trying to pull in the alt text that i have entered in the alt text field for each photo setting on wordpress.

Comment: The `alt` attribute should be attached to the `$_img` variable somewhere if it's defined (at least, if you're using the ACF Pro "Gallery" field), so you should be able to use `$_img['alt'];`. I've updated the code with that, as well as some hints on how to find the alt if it's not there for some reason (using a different type of field, etc)

Comment: Not using any Custom Fields for the Alt text. Its the alt fields that are found within the media gallery for all photos, so the default wordpress alt text field.

Comment: I understand that. Advanced Custom Fields is the name of the plugin that creates the `get_field()` function. If you do `print_r( $_img )`, what is the result?

Comment: I get an array with tons of data: [ID], [link], [name], [alt], plus a lot more. But at least its pulling in the alt text.

Comment: I do use ACF for the caption and title but i would like to pull in the default word press alt text

Comment: So did you try `alt="<?= esc_attr( $_img['alt'] ); ?>"` yet? Because again, using the Gallery field grabs the default WordPress Alt Text for each image.

Comment: alt="<?= esc_attr( $_img['alt'] ); doesnt bring in the alt text

Comment: Can you paste the output of `print_r( $_img )` somewhere, either pastebin or append it to your question? You mentioned it has the ID, Alt, etc in it. So it's in there somewhere.

Comment: This is what is outputed: https://pastebin.com/6mYPhiCG

Comment: For some reason (perhaps plugin version difference?) it's showing that it's all wrapped in the `$_img['photo']` parent level. Using `alt="<?= esc_attr( $_img['photo']['alt'] ); ?>"` instead should output the value you want. Mine is dropping it straight in the `$_img` level. Either way, you may want to [peruse the Do's & Don'ts of Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) for some tips on loopless array traversal